Primitive multiplier of a Ramanujan series
Let
$
z_0=4 \alpha_0 \beta_0,\quad \beta_0=1-\alpha_0, 
$
being $z_0$ an special or singular value of a Ramanujan-type series. The corresponding multiplier is defined by
$$
m_0=\frac{_2F_1(\frac1s, 1-\frac1s;1;\alpha_0)}{_2F_1(\frac1s,1-\frac1s;1;\beta_0)},
$$
where $\ell=4 \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{s}$ is the level, and $s \in \{6,4,3,2\}$ or equivalently $\ell \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.
QUESTION: We ask for exact methods to determine $m_0$.

I hope this is essentially asking how to evaluate the ratio $K/K'$ or equivalently nome $q$ given the invariant $G=(2kk')^{-1/12}$.
